# How do I Filter a table view by using TWO tables in MVC Controller?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm struggling with Filtering my table view based on TWO table attributes. I can display them fine using data from a single table, but once I add a filter from a second table and the Identity it won't display. Im trying "show results using TABLE 1 where Table1 ID == Table2 ID AND Table 2 User == User.identity.name"... in case it makes a difference... Table 1 is "Safes", Table 2 is a bridge table of "Users and Safes".
Any Help much appreciated :)

```
public ActionResult GetSafe(Users_and_Safe uas)
    {
        using (CBREntities2 dc = new CBREntities2())
        {

            var safe = dc.Safes.Where(a => a.Safe_ID == uas.Safe_ID && uas.User_ID == User.Identity.Name).Select(s => new { Safe_ID = s.Safe_ID, Department_ID = s.Department_ID, User_ID = s.User_ID }).ToList();
                return Json(new { data = safe }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

[image]

[image: Users And Safes Bridge Table]

[image: Safes Table]

Comment: For the more clear your question, please  provide the sample data of tables

Comment: I have added a picture of the table. To explain it... It needs to display ONLY the safes allocated to the User (It used to show ALL safes). Under the "Open Safe" column, is then a hyperlink taking it to another table which displays fine.

Comment: I said about SQL table data, not your front-end application table view

Comment: Sorry misunderstood! Tables have been added. I haven't added the Users table as that plays no part in this elements of code.

Comment: Did you debug your code? what the value is coming on "uas" parameter and the User.Identity.Name?

Comment: The value for Identity.Name correctly matches uas.User ID

Comment: Even if I remove the 2nd bit... a.Safe_ID == uas.User_ID doesn't work... I can only guess because each are from different tables?

Answer (score 1):

So I have found the answer and thought I would post for anyone in the future who has the issue:

```
public ActionResult GetSafeHome(Users_and_Safe uas)
    {
        using (CBREntities2 dc = new CBREntities2())
        {
            var allUAS = dc.Users_and_Safes.Where(b => b.User_ID == User.Identity.Name).Select(c => c.Safe_ID).ToList();
            var homeSafes = dc.Safes.Where(x => (allUAS.Contains(x.Safe_ID))).Select(s => new { Safe_ID = s.Safe_ID, Department_ID = s.Department_ID }).ToList();
            return Json(new { data = homeSafes }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```